# Properly structuring scriptDb for and Inventory System

Tags: google-apps-script

We have built a Inventory and Inspection Manager for our gear, each item type can be on a different schedule and can have multiple of the same item. We serialize all items for tracking.  My question is how can I structure the scriptDb to only have one object per serial number.  Currently I'm storing every inspection and movement separately and just iterate through by serial number. Is there a proper way to have it structured like the following with out overwriting a previous entry inside the inspHx section of the object?

{serialNumber, itemType, manufacturer, expDate, inspHx{multiple entries}}

if I get the item by serialNumber.inspHx and save a new record into it deletes the previous object in the inspHx. How can you continue to add new records to the inspHx of one serialNumber?

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database design can be a bit of an art and there is usually more than one way of reaching your goal. That said:

Instead of trying to store everything in a single object you might have two object types. There might be two buckets, so to speak, one for each data type. You would need to add an additional parameter to each object identifying its type or bucket. Type: meta or Type: inspHx

1. Meta data object that contains the information about the item that rarely changes. There should be only one of these per serial number.

2  Inspection objects, one for each inspection with date, status, etc.

Each type needs a common element or KEY which in this case would be the serial number.

When querying you would do two queries using the serial number for meta data and serial number plus any constraints on the inspection objects.

For a bit more see the Tables section at: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#tables